# Angular 4 button link to LazyLoading Module Route Not Working

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router

I have a button with a routerLink directive to a lazy loaded module. However the link is not working. While it is loaded in the browser address bar (when button is clicked) the component never gets loaded and in console i get a 404 error. What am i doing wrong.

The functionality i want to achieve is: when i go to /incidents/5 to get a filled form (from event with id = 5 for editing/updating) while when i go to /incidents/new to get an empty form to insert a new incident.

I suppose that the problem is probably in the IncidentsRoutingModule however i cannot make work.

My main app-routing-module is the following:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'incidents', loadChildren : 'app/incidents/incidents.module#IncidentsModule' },
  { path: 'patients', loadChildren: 'app/patients/patients.module#PatientsModule' },
  { path: 'doctors', loadChildren: 'app/doctors/doctors.module#DoctorsModule' },
  { path: 'clinics', loadChildren: 'app/clinics/clinics.module#ClinicsModule' },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules } )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The IncidentsModule is:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IncidentsRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    IncidentsComponent,
    IncidentDetailsComponent,
    IncidentsListComponent
  ],
  providers:[IncidentsService]
})
export class IncidentsModule { }
```

The IncidentsRoutingModule is:

```
const incidentsModuleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IncidentsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', component: IncidentsListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path:':id', component: IncidentDetailsComponent
          },

          {
            path: 'new', component: IncidentDetailsComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(incidentsModuleRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class IncidentsRoutingModule { }
```

My IncidentsComponent has a button with a routerLink Directive which is not working. Bellow is my IncidentsComponent:

```
@Component({
  // selector: 'app-incidents',
  template: `
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h3 style="margin:20px 20px 0px 20px;">Περιστατικά</h3>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="margin: 20px" routerLink="/incidents/new">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="margin-right: 10px"></i>
        Νέο Περιστατικό
      </button>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./incidents.component.css']
})
export class IncidentsComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? getting errors?

Comment: yes 404 not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as i suspected at the IncidentsRoutingModule. I changed it to the following and it worked as expected.

```
const incidentsModuleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IncidentsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', component: IncidentsListComponent,
      },
      {
        path:':id', component: IncidentDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'new', component: IncidentDetailsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Obviously what i have understood (don't know if this is correct, haven't found it or read it somewhere) is that children in lazy loaded Modules refers to the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` declaration.

In my situation i had only one 
`<router-outlet>` inside IncidentsComponent. So all paths must reside in a children object under IncidentsComponent. Adding children objects under other child components i suppose that works  only if these components also have `<router-outlet>` declarations?? Am i right????

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="margin: 20px" routerLink="new">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="margin-right: 10px"></i>
        Νέο Περιστατικό
      </button>
```

You could try adding `useHash: true` in the forRoot method of you main routing module

Comment: Exactly the same. Browser url get updated but i get error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). Any ideas??

Comment: Edited my answer